# Kotlin sealed classes assigning property constants

Tags: kotlin

```
kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
```

I have a sqlite table that has a Integer value for a column called direction. That will store the Integer property based on the enum constant.

i.e will insert `40` into the table:

```
saveDirection(Direction.Right.code)
```

I have a enum class written in kotlin with property constants assigned.

```
 enum class Direction(val code: Int) {
        UP(10),
        DOWN(20),
        LEFT(30),
        RIGHT(40),
        NONE(0)
    }
```

I am wondering if I can do the same with sealed classes

```
sealed class Direction {
    abstract val code: Int

    data class Up(override val code: Int): Direction()
    data class Down(override val code: Int): Direction()
    data class Left(override val code: Int): Direction()
    data class Right(override val code: Int): Direction()
    data class None(override val code: Int): Direction()
}
```

However, this won't work as the `saveDirection(direction: Int)` is expecting an Int value:

```
saveDirection(Direction.Right(40))
```

Is this possible to assign constant properties to sealed classes so that you can get the constant property like in enums?

Thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Why do you want to replace your enum with a sealed class?

Comment: Yes, I was looking to save the state in the sqlite table. And was looking to have a property constant associated with each state that would be an Int value in the sqlite table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* use sealed classes like this:

```
sealed class Direction(val code: Int) { 
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean = other is Direction && code == other.code
    override fun hashCode(): Int = code
}

class Up : Direction(10)
class Down : Direction(20)
class Left : Direction(30)
class Right : Direction(40)
class None : Direction(0)
```

However, given the limited context of the question, it is unclear what exactly you would gain by this. In fact, in this simple case, Kotlin does not allow your subclasses to be marked as `data class`:

```
Data class must have at least one primary constructor parameter
```

The solution provided above does not have any advantage over enums, in fact it is more verbose and error-prone than an `enum`-based definition, so why not just use those?